# Logging session state in Application Insights for Azure Cache for Redis

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, caching, redis

I'm working on ASP.NET web application connected to Azure. Is it possible to see not only common data about connected clients and expired keys, but also more detailed logs per session (some session state info as session ID, ect.)
current data in Insights for Azure Cache for Redis

[image]

I configured session state storing in the cache as in [this topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider#store-aspnet-session-state-in-the-cache), but can't find information I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps to view the Session Info in `ASP.Net` Application for Azure Cache for Redis.

- Created `ASP.Net` Application in Visual Studio.
- Copy the `Hostname` from Azure Redis Cache `Properties` .

[image]

- And Password (access Key) from Redis Cache =>`Access Keys` => `Primary Key`.

[image]

***My `Web.config` file:***

```cs
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="***.redis.cache.windows.net,abortConnect=false,ssl=true,allowAdmin=true,password=***"/>

  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
    <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
      <providers>       
        <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="***.redis.cache.windows.net" accessKey="***" ssl="true" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="Session" />
      <add name="Session" type="Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModuleAsync, Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

- Publish the Code to Azure App Service.
- Enable Application Insights while Publishing to Azure itself.

[image]

- In your deployed Application make sure `Application Insights` is Enabled.

[image]

- You can see the No. of sessions in `Application Insights` => `Sessions`.

[image]

- If you click on `View More Insights` tab, we will get the below data.

[image]

- Click on `View session timeline` to get the session ID.

[image]

[image]

Reference taken from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-web-app-howto).

Comment: Thank you so much! It's very helpful. Is it also possible to view every session timeline? Need to see more than "any 5" or "most active" sessions.

Comment: Yes, We can see all the sessions timelines. To see all the sessions, check in the [Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5ABh.png)

Comment: All the sessions timelines can be seen as separate logs will be created for each session.

Comment: Click on `View session timeline` and you can see the no. of sessions is shown as [AppInsightsSnapshotCollectorLogs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpeMi.png).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed - to see all the sessions timelines. 
But in Logs traces I don't see timeline of current session. Tried to add session_id column, doesn't help. [current session](https://i.imgur.com/IBoJmRx.jpg) and [my logs](https://i.imgur.com/X7Es5gT.jpg)

Comment: Not sure about the `Logs`, but you can check the details in `View session timeline` clearly.